# On tab key request focus on spinner-Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a registration form where flow goes as EditText1->EditText2->Spinner->Editext3 ,but on tab press the of EditText2 control is transferred to editText3 and not Spinner How can i do that in android??Can anyone help plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this before your Oncreate()

```
Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1); 
spin.setFocusable(true); 
spin.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
spin.requestFocus();
```

Comment: how can i write the above code before onCreate().??